# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable" while using fetchone()[0]

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having an issue with `fetchone()` function on the `sqlite3` lib object `connect`:

- I do a query that might not always return a value;
- Check if it returned a value;
- In case it returns a value, I give that value to my variable using `fetchone()[0]`;

Executed code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT average from logs WHERE process = (?)", (process,))
print c.fetchone()
print "\n"
if c.fetchone() is not None:
    lastaverage = c.fetchone()[0]
    print lastaverage
    print average
    if average > lastaverage * 1.3:
        print "The process took too long to execute."
    else:
        lastaverage = 0
        print "Script entered here!!"
```

And here's my output:

```
Script entered here!!

(u'0',)


Script entered here!!

(u'200',)


Script entered here!!

None


Script entered here!!

(u'0',)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 87, in <module>
    lastaverage = c.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable
```

From what I searched, this is the same exact error that happens if I try to do `lastaverage = None[0]` which makes sense. But this line is only executed IF `c.fetchone()` returns a value.

Using `if c.fetchone()[0] is not None:` returns the same error, but on the if line! This seems like a clue but I don't know to what exactly. I also tried using `if c.fetchone()[0]:` instead of the `is not None` condition, but the behavior is the same.

My python version is 2.6.6. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with _SQLite_ _API_, but let's say that `c.execute` will return a `QuerySet`. Every time you call `c.fetchone()` it will consume an element from it (and eventually it will run out of elements). You should assign `c.fetchone()` to some variable and use that instead of calling `c.fetchone()` multiple times. Note that `c.fetchone()` from `if c.fetchone() is not None:` is different than the one from `lastaverage = c.fetchone()[0]`.

Comment: Hmm I see what you mean, but I've also tried: "lastaverage = c.fetchone()" and then "lastaverage = "lastaverage[0]", and it returns the exact same error. I can use a second variable and test but does it make sense to use a second variable just to do that?

Comment: You can use only one variable, but assign `fetch_one = c.fetchone()` just under `c.execute` (and remove all other `c.fetchone()` calls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the mistake you are making is that second call to `fetchone()`, which almost by definition can only be called once on a cursor that has executed a query returning a single row. Try saving the result and using the saved value rather than calling `fetchone()` twice without executing a second query. The first call exhausts the result set, so the second one returns `None`.

`fetchone` returns a single row, so `fetchone()[0]` gives you the first (and in this case the only) column from that row. but only when `fetchone` is actually returning a row!

Comment: You were right, thank you so much. What threw me off was that I could print the value AND use it on the if. But somehow the value is only resetted on the if. I'm using a variable called result and do the same operations with result instead of c.fetchone(). Is this the correct way? Using a second variable just for it?

Comment: That should do it. The `print` pretty much guarantees that you will always be testing `None`, which is certainly not what you want!