# Why TypeError is showing while storing fetchone() value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, typeerror

I have a table `set_reminders`. I am running a `SELECT` query to fetch a row. Even after storing the `fetchone()` value in a variable and then using it for further use like told [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235712/typeerror-nonetype-object-is-unsubscriptable-while-using-fetchone0) it is showing **TypeError**. Below is the code to my problem.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    recur_next = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['btn']=='XYZ':
        date = request.form['date']
        subject = 'Event'
        reminders='Placement Drive'
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        search = cur.execute('SELECT DATE,SUBJECT,DESCRIPTION,RECUR_NEXT FROM set_reminder WHERE DATE=%s AND SUBJECT=%s AND DESCRIPTION=%s',(date,subject,reminders))
        data = cur.fetchall()
        a = cur.fetchone()
        recur_next = a['RECUR_NEXT']
        print(recur_next)
        cur.close()

    return '''<form method="post">
    <input type="date" name="date">
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="XYZ">
    </form>'''
```

```
 File "def.py", line 22, in index
    recur_next = a['RECUR_NEXT']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This is the error that is showing. Please help me out.

Comment: If you `fetchall` first, then `fetchone` probably doesn't return anything anymore…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchall()` emptied the results from the cursor, so `fetchone()` return `None`, and if you use `fetchone()` first `fetchall()` will be an empty list. If you need both work only with `fetchall()` and take the data from there.

Comment: if i do ```fetchone()``` 1st then ```fetchall()``` will it create any problem because I need output from the calls

Comment: @BarefacedBear It will be an empty list. Use just `fetchall()` and work with it.